# Computations of derivations, $d^2$, of a (Grothendieck) spectral sequence

Tags: homological-algebra

The maps $d^1:E_1\rightarrow E_1$ have a nice description. Is there any text providing us with a description of the higher derivations $d^2:E_2\rightarrow E_2$ arising from a Grothendieck spectral sequence?

Comment: What is a Grothendieck spectral sequence?

Comment: it's usually the spectral sequence arising when composing two (derived) functors

Comment: @abx, the Grothendieck spectral sequence is a spectral sequence which   approximates the derived functors of the composition of two functors by the composition  of the derived functors of each of those functors. See, "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" written by Rotman.